# Ubuntu Launcher PHP working directory

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, php, launcher

I have created a launcher for PHP:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=PHP
Terminal=true
Exec=/usr/bin/php %f
Icon=/home/virsacer/Icons/php.png
```

When I open a PHP-file with it, the working directory is set to "/" instead of the location of the file - so I cant include or work with other files from the directory :/

Apparently there is a "Path" Option for launchers, but this seems to be static...

I also tried to include a command like this:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/php -B "chdir('%d');" -F %f
```

But then the shell opens and closes so fast, that I cant even see the output...

Is there a way to set the working dir without having a command in each file?